# Unable to encode UIImage into data for POST request

Tags: ios, swift, request, uiimage

I'm converting a UIImage into data to be sent to a server via a http POST request. While preparing the body for the request, the function `createBody` is called, and the image data that is passed to this function is `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)!`

```
static func createBody(parameters: [String: String],
                boundary: String,
                data: Data,
                mimeType: String,
                filename: String) -> Data {

    let body = NSMutableData()

    let boundaryPrefix = "--\(boundary)\r\n"

    for (key, value) in parameters {

        body.appendString(boundaryPrefix)
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
    }

    body.appendString(boundaryPrefix)
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(data) // theres something about appending this image data that is causing problems

    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--".appending(boundary.appending("--")))

    print(body as Data)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "unable to print data")

    return body as Data
}
```

The console reads:

```
368185 bytes
unable to print data
```

When the image data is not appended to the body, `body` is printed without any issues. When the image data is appended, it is clearly there, since the size of `body` is considerably greater (368185 bytes vs 191 bytes), yet the next line reads `unable to print data`. What is it about this UIImage data that is not allowing it to be encoded along with the other text in the body? If it's to do with the encoding, then how can I have the body printed with both the text and data and how should it be formatted to be sent to a server via POST?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the size. That's a lot of text to try to print to the console. Have you actually tried sending the request?

Comment: I think UIImage data can not be converted to string. If it gets converted some how, it will be too big to print. If your request is successful, then don't bother printing it to console.

Comment: Yes it is a large file in all fairness. The request has been sent, with a response suggesting that the file was not uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert the image data to a `String` assuming it is UTF8 data. It isn't and therefore no `String` is produced. The image data is likely to have many non-printable characters in it.

As an alternative, you could print a base64 encoded string from your data:

```
print(data.base64EncodedString())
```

Comment: This is also how OP would most likely want to append the data to the body as well. In my experience most servers will want base 64 encoded string or a raw byte array for the image data. For accessing raw bytes I would consider bridging to `NSData`. `(data as NSData).bytes` would work.

Comment: @NSGangster No need to cast to NSData. If you would like to get the data bytes all you need is to initialize a new array `Array(data)`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the tip I'll definitely use that.